# My tumblr chat posts arn't working properly

Tags: css

my tumblr chat posts look jumbled and broken on my theme and i cant figure out whats wrong with the coding.
this is my tumblr
http://fuckyouandyourmelons.tumblr.com/

this is the code

```
{block:Chat}
{block:Title}<div class="title">{Title}</div>{/block:Title}
<div class="text">
{block:Lines}<div class="{Alt}">
<div class="line">{block:Label}<span class="name">{Label}</span>{/block:Label} {Line}<br /></div></div>
{/block:Lines}
</div>
{/block:Chat}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS is causing the issue:

```
.line {
  top: 13px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Remove `width:0px` and it should look like this:

[image]